# rename specific columns in dataframes in a list

Tags: r

I have a list with several dataframes, each dataframe correspond to an election, say 2010, 2013, ..., 2021.

For each dataframe, I want to add the year to every column name except the first three columns. So I'm trying to add the year to [,4:end_column] using a for loop:

```
for (i in names(SECCIONES_year)) {
  year <- (substr(i, nchar(i)-4, nchar(i)))
  end_column <- ncol(SECCIONES_year[[i]])

  past_names <- names(SECCIONES_year[[i]][ ,4:end_column])

  colnames(SECCIONES_year[[i]][,4:end_column]) <- paste(past_names, year, sep="")

}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work but it does if I work with all column names as:

```
colnames(SECCIONES_year[[i]]) <- paste(past_names, year, sep=)
```

I tried with colnames, names and setNames but failed every try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres no need for comma in the second bracket, before "4":

```
colnames(SECCIONES_year[[i]])[4:ncol(SECCIONES_year[[i]])] <- paste(past_names, year, sep="")
```

Answer (score 3):

With `base R`, an opiton is to loop over the `list` as well as the `names` of the `list` with `Map`, extract the `substr`ing from the names (could be done outside the loop as well as the `substr` is vectorized), then assign the subset of column names of the `data.frame` elements by `paste`ing the `substr`ing 'year' with the corresponding column names, and return the data.frame

```
SECCIONES_year <- Map(function(x, nm)
         {
        year <- substr(nm, nchar(nm)-4, nchar(nm))
        names(x)[4:ncol(x)] <- paste0(names(x)[4:ncol(x)], year)
        x  
    }, 

      SECCIONES_year, names(SECCIONES_year))
```

---

In the OP's code, it could be assignment error i.e. instead of  `colnames(SECCIONES_year[[i]][,4:end_column])`  it would be `colnames(SECCIONES_year[[i]])[,4:end_column]` i.e. as an example

```
lst1 <- list(data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10),
    data.frame(col3 = 3:5, col4 = 4:6))
names(lst1) <- c("a", "b")
```

Checking the output with both the methods

```
# OP's method
> for(nm in names(lst1)) colnames(lst1[[nm]][2]) <- "hello"
> lst1
$a
  col1 col2
1    1    6
2    2    7
3    3    8
4    4    9
5    5   10

$b
  col3 col4
1    3    4
2    4    5
3    5    6
# modified
> for(nm in names(lst1)) colnames(lst1[[nm]])[2] <- "hello"
> lst1
$a
  col1 hello
1    1     6
2    2     7
3    3     8
4    4     9
5    5    10

$b
  col3 hello
1    3     4
2    4     5
3    5     6
```